# SonarQube showing a login message

Tags: sonarqube

I want that appears a message when a user login SonarQube (6.7 version) but I don't now how to do it.
I've looked for a plugin to customize the look and I tried to find the javascript file that is listening for a login button click without success.

Can somebody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: @kenlukas the desired behavior is that when a user login in Sonarqube appears a text message. When I login I get in /projects and if I could change this and get in /about the problem will be solved because in administration configuration option, in Look & Feel section I can put text that is shown in /about page.